# Structuring a multi-package Python project with editable installs in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-poetry

At our company we've split up our Python code base into multiple packages. To allow for a decent development workflow, we use editable installs.

**Setup**

- We have three packages, structure like so:

  ```
  .
  ├── api
  │   └── pyproject.toml
  ├── db
  │   └── pyproject.toml
  └── core
      └── pyproject.toml
  ```
- The dependencies flow as follows: `api` -> `db` -> `core`.
- We use a multi-root Visual Studio Code workspace, with each of the packages as a separate project folder.
- We use poetry and virtual environments (on per project folder).

**Issues**

We've had nothing but trouble:

- IntelliSense seems to work intermittently. Open one file and identifiers are clickable. Open another and they aren't. Reset the interpreter path (either at the workspace or project level) and something starts working while something else stops working.
- Test discovery frequently fails for one project folder or another. Again issues are intermittent and seem to be triggered by "interesting" interactions around what interpreter gets used when.

**Questions**

Which of the below approaches will mitigate or avoid the problems above?

- One virtual environment per project or one for the whole workspace?
- Set the interpreter at the workspace-level or project-level? Both?
- Multi-root workspace or single-root workspace?

Comment: We use one virtual environment per project where I work with separate individual interpreters per env per project and it works very well.

Comment: why use multiple virt envs? You have to maintain/install stuff multiple times, and the  app uses only 1 python interpreter. Why use a different python interpreter for each workspace. Why use multi-root, do you have different git repos per package?

Comment: For your information, I have the same problem with Visual Studio Code IntelliSense (which is based on PyLance) of not understanding the code structure. However the same problem does not appear with PyCharm with its own language server process, so I assume it's PyLance specific configuration problem. I have no idea how to resolve, in my case I just use PyCharm to edit Python.